# Visual Studio Team Services - Test Plan Creation : I am a basic Paid subscriber and not able to create any test Plan

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I would like to know how to upgrade the subscription to access/create test plan in Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online). I have right now Basic Paid subscription and i am told that this will work for creating test cases.

This is what i am seeing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDsXH.png)

This is i am suppose to see:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP1ss.png)

Please provide solution

Answer (score 0):

Test Manager extension is not free. You can have 90 days for free trial. Refer to this link for details: [Try Visual Studio Team Services extensions for free](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/try-additional-features-vs). And then, you can buy it from extension page: [Test Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [features list](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-feature-matrix-vs.aspx), Basic access doesn't include the ability to create test plans and test cases. You'll need the Test Manager extension, as mentioned.